# aws elastic beanstalk do NOT invoke private API

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

We have started a PHP beanstalk application, first we tested the API as public and it was working, then we tried to make the API private to be called through a VPC Endpoint following the tutorial and instructions but no luck.

We have created the Endpoint and resource policy to income the API
We have attached the Resource policy to the API

While troubleshooting, API can be invoked from the same EC2 instance (`curl -X GET https://***` ) and it was successful, but the issue is from beanstalk application it never hits the API, there are no CloudWatch logs either

Here is the code we use to invoke the API from cloud watch "`https://API-ID-vpce-*****.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Pro/calc/?test=`"

We already allowed the HTTPS inbound and outbound on security groups

Honestly we have tried everything since 10 days with no luck

Appreciate your support into this

Kind Regards

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217299/discussion-on-question-by-hamza-qawasmi-aws-elastic-beanstalk-do-not-invoke-priv).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The cause of the issue  remains undetermined. In this case a support ticket will be placed with **AWS support** for assistance.